Correct div from the google finance html to obtain the annual return on the stock of this url
How can I extract the correct div from the google finance html to obtain the annual return on the stock of this url https://www.google.com/finance/quote/NVO:NYSE?window=1Y?
I made this code to webscraping this page and I cant get the correct data. How can I fix
def parse_stock_info(self, html):
         soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        name_tag = soup.find("div", class_="zzDege")
        price_tag = soup.find("div", class_="YMlKec fxKbKc")
        performance_tag = soup.find("div", class_="JwB6zf")
   

        name = name_tag.text if name_tag else "N/A"
        price = price_tag.text if price_tag else "N/A"
        performance = performance_tag.text if performance_tag else "N/A"
    
        return {
            "name": name,
            "price": price,
            "performance": performance
        }


saying 'i can't get the correct data' but giving no actual detail as to what you are getting (if anything) is not helpful.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

suggest you look at the yfinance package , it provides an easy to use i/face rather than trying to scrape webpages
trivial example below using yfinance https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/.
cat lamberto.py 
import yfinance as yf

ticker = "BAC"

print( f'attempting to download for {ticker}\n\n' )
history = yf.download(ticker, period="1Y")
    
print(history.head())

csv=ticker + '.csv'
print( f'saving to {csv}' )
history.to_csv( csv )

#
# test code
#
python3 lamberto.py
attempting to download for BAC


[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
                 Open       High        Low      Close  Adj Close    Volume
Date                                                                       
2023-06-08  29.280001  29.379999  28.990000  29.230000  28.385082  41483100
2023-06-09  29.200001  29.400000  29.080000  29.270000  28.423925  32671800
2023-06-12  29.299999  29.559999  28.910000  29.129999  28.287971  41011300
2023-06-13  29.129999  29.799999  29.030001  29.400000  28.550167  42718800
2023-06-14  29.570000  29.730000  28.990000  29.120001  28.278265  38322800
saving to BAC.csv

there's also https://pypi.org/project/googlefinance/, https://python-yahoofinance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
and a host of others
